# Remove custom posts that match taxonomy value

Tags: posts, taxonomy, customization

I have a custom post type 'listings' and within that a taxonomy called 'status' where the posts are either 'standard' or 'premium'.

What SQL query (or other method), could I use to delete all custom posts where the taxonomy 'status' has the value 'standard' ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

something along these lines should do it:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listings',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'status',
            'field' => YOUR FIELD NAME HERE???
            'terms' => 'standard'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

foreach( $query->posts as $id ){
           wp_delete_post( $id->ID, TRUE );
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume the field name would be 'slug'?